# Magento 2 How to change media base url programatically

Tags: magento2, url, media

Does anyone know how we can change magento 2 media base url programatically ?

Comment: I mean change for upload image or else?

Comment: yes image is already upoaded but i want to update only base url e.g https://magento233/pub/media/image1.jpg to https://customurl/image1.jpg

Comment: So, I think you transfer your localhost to the new server right?

Comment: yes right i want to upload my images to server new media url path

Comment: Do this in MySQL instead. `UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'customurl' WHERE path LIKE 'web/%secure/base_media_url';`

Comment: but i want programatically

Answer (score 1):

Please, use interfaces for interacting with Magento.
If you are developing a custom module, you can use `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface` to write configuration, and  `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` to read configuration.

Additionally you can use the magento command line: `php bin/magento config:set`

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, we need to use Dependency Injection to get an instance of `Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config`, which can then be used to save the config programmatically. The `base_media_url` needs to be stored once for the secured (HTTPS) value, and once for the unsecured (HTTP) value:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\Somewhere;

use Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;

class Something {

    protected $_config;

    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->_config = $config;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $this->_config->saveConfig('web/secure/base_media_url','/your/path/', 'default', 0);
        $this->_config->saveConfig('web/unsecure/base_media_url','/your/path/', 'default', 0);
    }
    
}
```

The `saveConfig()` [parameters](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config.php) are `$path`, `$value`, `$scope`, and `$scopeId`, with only the first two being required.